# Infinitesimal criteria for unramified morphism on stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, stacks

In an Artin stack, the tangent complex is fundamentally a derived object, often viewed as a 2-term complex via some quotient presentation, as discussed in Raskin's note [here](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Sept22(Dmodstack1).pdf), for example. In particular, the tangent "space" at a point is a two-term complex of say, vector spaces, which we can view as a quotient stack. For example, at a point $\mathcal{E}$ on $Bun_G$ over a curve $X$, the tangent space can reasonably be viewed as $$T_{\mathcal{E}} Bun_G = [H^1(X, \mathfrak{g}_{\mathcal{E}})/H^0(X, \mathfrak{g}_{\mathcal{E}})].$$

Say we have a map of smooth, locally finitely presented stacks $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ and a point $x \in \mathcal{X}$. What is the appropriate condition on the induced morphisms of tangent complexes $T_x \mathcal{X} \to T_{F(x)} \mathcal{Y}$ in order to conclude that $f$ is unramified?

In a triangulated category the property of being a monomorphism is somewhat silly, so that doesn't seem right. More naively, one could ask for injectivity (or isomorphism) on either, or both of the cohomology groups (in the example above, on $H^0$ and on $H^1$). **Which is the right notion?**

My motivating example: for $P \subseteq G$ a parabolic subgroup of a reductive group, Behrend's conjecture shows that the map $Bun_{P} \to Bun_{G}$ (in good characteristic) induces isomorphisms on $H^0$ and injections on $H^1$. This feels clearly sufficient, but perhaps stronger than necessary.

Comment: A locally finitely presented $1$-morphism of algebraic stacks is unramified if and only if the relative cotangent complex has vanishing $h^{-1}$ and $h^{0}$.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. For nice enough stacks it should dualize to the same condition on the tangent complex. By the LES in cohomology I believe this to be equivalent to the conditions I have in the example -- Isomorphism in h^-1, injection in h^0.